# Problem with incrementing of a cell in a google sheets offset formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have three formulas, relatively the same, but with a different column for each.

```
=OFFSET('War Layouts'!$B$2,(ROW(B1)-1)*7,0)
=OFFSET('War Layouts'!$F$2,(ROW(F1)-1)*7,0)
=OFFSET('War Layouts'!$J$2,(ROW(J1)-1)*7,0)
```

The formula's do exactly what I want, but I want to copy them down my column to repeat the functionality.

When I copy them down, the row number changes to (B4),(F4),(J4), etc. And nothing else increases, which is what I want.

I want the row value to be (B2),(F2),(J2) when I copy down the formula and I just cannot wrack my brain on how to achieve this.

Edit: For additional information, i'm providing a spreadsheet example of what i'm working with.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fxc4KcAYlh7vfg7UV0oestKdyuf0LrpvzJmyt0JbAzg/edit?usp=sharing

Essentially I want pull the 'Name' Field, 3 time's a week, every 7 rows.
So day 1 is the B column, Day 2 is F, Day 3 is J.

On the 'Stats' Sheet, is where I have the formula's above. The first 3 row's are correct, but the next three have B4,F4,J4 instead of B2,F2,J2, etc.

Comment: A hacky way to do this could be to have a column keep track of either the row number or the row number mod 3 (so 3 concurrent rows have the same value `x`, but the next 3 have `x+1`). Then reference that value to generate your `ROW(x)` formula, or possibly something like `MOD(ROW(x), 3)`.

Comment: Tyler, you'll always get the best help here if you share your sheet (or a copy of it) with permission set to "Anyone with the link can edit." Reading your description, there are just too many unknowns. If you choose to share a sheet, fill in the values that you would like to have the formulas produce and leave a note explaining which range(s) the formula(s) should be applied to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may do what you want, similar to what WOUNDEDStevenJones has described.  Since dragging down will normally increment the row numbers in the equations by 1, use `INDIRECT` to calculate the new row number, based on the current row number divided by 3.  The only trick is factoring in your starting row.  Here are the three new formulae to replace your existing formulae:

```
=OFFSET($B$2, ROW( INDIRECT("B" &    INT((row()+2)/3)))  *7  ,  0)
=OFFSET($F$2, ROW( INDIRECT("F" &    INT((row()+2)/3)))  *7  ,  0)
=OFFSET($J$2, ROW( INDIRECT("J" &    INT((row()+2)/3)))  *7  ,  0)
```

If you put these anywhere on rows 1,2 and 3 (one above the other), they can be dragged down as a group of three.  You can test it out by taking just one part, `=ROW( INDIRECT("B" & INT((row()+2)/3)))`, and dragging this down.  You'll see it increments the row number by one every three rows.

The only trick is getting the starting value right.  If you don't want to place the first formula in row 1, you need to adjust the "+2" amount downwards by 1, for each row you move down.  So +1 if starting on row 2, +0 if on 3, -1 if on 4, etc.

Let me know if this helps, or if you need more explanation.

Comment: I can get this to work, but not for the first 3 columns, b2, f2, j2. But it pulls the cells every 7 rows, down the entire document. So I think I can work with this.

Comment: If you have any issues, and want to share a copy of your sheet, I'll be happy to help if I can.  Not sure why it can't work for the first three columns - do you mean the very first three values for those formulae?

Comment: And if the answer is useful, please up-vote it, or mark it a correct answer, to help others with a similar issue.